# Not able to create spy on method

Tags: angular, testing

### My service is

```
var testappserviceone = angular.module('testappserviceonemodule',[])

testappserviceone.factory('testappServiceone',[function(){
    return function (x,y) {

        function addobj (x,y){
            return x+y;
        }

        return{
            add:addobj
        }
    }
}]);
```

### My test suite is

```
describe('testappserviceone add method functionality', function(){

    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(testappServiceone(10,15),'add').and.callThrough();
    });

    it('testappServiceone add method functionality', function() {
        testappServiceone(10,15).add();
        expect(testappServiceone(10,15).add).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

### The Exception I am getting is

Expected a spy, but got Function.

I think spy() is not creating a spy . Please help me in understanding and solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Every time when we evaluate this expression/call function it returns new object with new function in property add

```
testappServiceone(10,15) // -> Object A
testappServiceone(10,15) // -> Object A'
// A !== A'
```

### In this case I should write something like this

```
var foo = testappServiceone(10,15);
spyOn(foo, 'add');
foo.add()

expect(foo.add).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

### For Ref : https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2751